# Apache Camel/Spring boot disable tracing

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

In my Apache Camel/Spring Boot application console I see tons of camel tracing starting with below. According to [this](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/tracer.html) camel.springboot.tracing=false should disable it but it doesn't work. Looking for the right way to disable tracing.

```
[http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1] INFO org.apache.camel.Tracing
```

Comment: are u using log4j2 or logback ?

Comment: I'm maintaining logging at application.properties level. Tried below two but did not help `log4j.org.apache.camel=Error
logging.org.apache.camel=Error`

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using logback.xml,

give a try on this:

```
<logger name="org.apache.camel" level="Error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

> If log4j.properties then:

```
log4j.org.apache.camel=Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by removing trace="true" from `<camel:camelContext trace="true">`